# How to produce rolling count per minute?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a counter attached to ISR:

```
void ISR_impulse() {
  CNT++;
}
```

and I want to calculate rolling count per minute with arbitrary update rate.

However I can only get it to update every minute:

```
void loop() {    
  if (t - t0 > 60000) {
    CPM = CNT - CNT0;
    t0 = t;
    CNT0 = CNT;      
  }

  t = millis();
  delay(100);
}
```

Requirement:

- Rolling count with a window of 1 minute, and arbitrary update rate like 1 second ?
- CPU has other tasks to do, which might take a significant amount of time.
- SAMD21 has pulse period measurement in TC, but I have no idea how to set it up.

Partial solution one by [edgar bonet](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/7508/edgar-bonet):

```
  static uint8_t buf[60];
  static uint8_t idx;
  static uint32_t t0;
  static uint16_t CNT0;
  static uint8_t cpm;

  if (millis() - t0 >= 1000) {
    t0 = millis();
    uint16_t cps = CNT - CNT0;
    CNT0 = CNT;
    cpm += cps - buf[idx];
    buf[idx] = cps;
    if (++idx >= 60) idx = 0;
  }
```

How ever this only works if the loop code finishes in less than 1ms.

Comment: set up a FIFO buffer ... the ISR pushes decimal 60 into the buffer .... every second, a separate program routine decrements each of the values in the buffer by one, counts non-zero values and returns the count

Comment: While rewriting the code of my answer, you introduced a couple of errors: 1. By updating `t0` with `t0 = millis();`, you make the tiny timing errors cumulative. If you update it with `t0 += 1000;` they are not cumulative: they only create a small amount of jitter, which is somewhat averaged-out by the subsequent running average. 2. By reading `CNT` twice with interrupts enabled, you create a race condition. If `CNT` is updated by the ISR between the two reads, you miss one pulse.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update every second a one minute running average, you
have no choice but store in memory the counts you got the previous
60 seconds. You store them in a ring buffer, so that every new
reading replaces the oldest one. Then, every second:

- you add to the CPM count the number of counts you got this second
- you subtract the number of counts you got on the second that just got
  out of the sliding window.

I would implement that logic this way:

```
const uint32_t ONE_SECOND = 1000;

uint16_t counts_per_minute;
uint16_t previous_counts[60];
size_t counts_pos;

void loop() {
    static uint32_t previous_second;
    if (millis() - previous_second >= ONE_SECOND) {
        previous_second += ONE_SECOND;
        noInterrupts();
        uint16_t CNT_copy = CNT;
        interrupts();
        static uint16_t CNT_previous;
        uint16_t second_count = CNT_copy - CNT_previous;
        CNT_previous = CNT_copy;
        counts_per_minute += second_count - previous_counts[counts_pos];
        previous_counts[counts_pos] = second_count;
        if (++counts_pos >= 60) counts_pos = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that:

- The timing variable is updated with `previous_second += ONE_SECOND`
  rather than `previous_second = now` in order to avoid the accumulation
  of small timing errors.
- The counter that is updated in the ISR has to be read only once,
  with interrupts disabled. Otherwise the interrupt may change it while
  you are in the middle of reading it.

Comment: So it's a moving average with count-per-update-period as elements ? Wouldn't the noInterrupts() cause the counter to miss some counts ?

Comment: It would be perfect of you could add code to account for millis() < 60000 situation.

Comment: @7E10FC9A: You cannot meaningfully compute a one minute rolling average in less than one minute.

Comment: @7E10FC9A: `noInterrupts()` will not make you miss an interrupt. If an interrupt request fires while interrupts are disabled, it is put on hold and served right after the `interrupts()` call. Only if two instances of the same request fire within this period do you miss an interrupt. But since they are been disabled for less than half a microsecond, this could only happen with an interrupt rate _way_ above what the Arduino can handle.

Comment: The code does not work if CPU has other tasks to do. The sampling interval is not guaranteed to be 1000ms.

Comment: @7E10FC9A: If you program in a _non blocking fashion_, your `loop()` should always execute very fast. If it takes more than a millisecond, you are most likely doing something wrong. With a very fast `loop()`, the inaccuracies will be tiny, and likely irrelevant. If your accuracy requirement is really so high that a fraction of a millisecond does matter, then program a timer to fire an interrupt every millisecond, and update `counts_per_minute` within the ISR.

Comment: MCU only have one thread, so it's difficult to make the loop code non-blocking. Let's say what would you do if there are other tasks that require CPU time >>1ms at random?

Comment: @7E10FC9A: In such a case I would use a timer interrupt. My point is that it is uncommon to actually need 1 ms of CPU time at once. If `loop()` takes more than 1 ms, it is more than likely that most of these CPU cycles are waisted delaying or busy-waiting for some event (i.e. “blocking”). Then you can make it non blocking by using a finite state machine and/or the technique shown in the Blink Without Delay tutorial.

Comment: Q doesn't say, but Is `uint16_t` large enough for the count/sec? //  If the `CNT` interrupt is accurate, then any errors introduced by the timing of the  samples are balanced by corresponding errors in the following second.    If the loop takes more than a second it could fall behind and overcount the minute, but short of that, the jitters should take care of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You need a First-In, First-Out buffer (FIFO) so that the oldest data drops off to make room for the newest. This is usually done with a circular buffer - an array whose beginning / end point change as data is added. (For comparison, the simplistic way is an array whose contents gets moved down (toward i = 0) each time you need to add a datum. But moving data is slow, so remembering where the oldest entry is, replacing it with the newest one, and updating the remembered oldest-data location gives a huge permormance improvement.

Secondly, you need to define how responsive your counter needs to be - how many updates per minute you'll need. That's the number of elements you need in the array.

Evaluating the immediately-passed minute's count is as simple as summing the array, which can be done without caring where the begin/end point is. Sum from 0 to N-1; the result will be the same.